# window.print() freezing in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Working on some pages, built mostly in classic asp. I am trying use window.print() on a few of my pages but for some reason it is stalling on me. It pops up and asks what printer to use, after choosing and clicking ok....it stalls up and have to end the IE task. Here is my link tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" >print window</a>
```

This works very well in all other browsers. The only thing I can think of is that I have an @media print tag in my CSS which I know is not fully supported. Would having this tag on the page cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="window.print();"` is enough on its own — no need for `return false`. Since you're not linking anywhere, you should use a `<button>` instead of an anchor. You should also use an event listener rather than `onclick`.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="print-page">Print</button>
```

JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById('print-page');

if (window.addEventListener) {
    button.addEventListener('click', window.print, false);
}
else {
    button.attachEvent('onclick', window.print);
}
```

If you're having trouble styling a `<button>` or `<input type="button">` element to your liking (older browsers can be finicky), you can use a `<span>` but be sure to add `role="button"` so that assistive technologies and other machines (search engines, etc) are aware that the element should be treated like a button.